# Converting word frequency to a graphical histogram in python

Tags: python, formula, frequency

This is what I have right now, thanks to Pavel Anossov. I am trying to convert the word frequency that has been outputed into asterisks.

```
import sys
import operator 
from collections import Counter
def candidateWord():


   with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:
      text = f.read()
   words = [w.strip('!,.?1234567890-=@#$%^&*()_+')for w in text.lower().split()]
            #word_count[words] = word_count.get(words,0) + 1
   counter = Counter(words)

   print("\n".join("{} {}".format(*p) for p in counter.most_common()))

candidateWord()
```

This is what I have right now as an output.

```
how 3

i 2

am 2

are 2

you 2

good 1

hbjkdfd 1
```

The formula I want to try and use is the most frequent word occurs M times and the current word occurs N times, the number of asterisks printed is:

```
(50 * N) / M
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll put the asterisks on the left to avoid aligning words:

```
...
counter = Counter(words)
max_freq = counter.most_common()[0][1]
for word, freq in sorted(counter.most_common(), key=lambda p: (-p[1], p[0])):
    number_of_asterisks = (50 * freq ) // max_freq     # (50 * N) / M
    asterisks = '*' * number_of_asterisks        # the (50*N)/M asterisks
    print('{:>50} {}'.format(asterisks, word))
```

The `:>50` format string means "left-pad with spaces to 50 characters".

- `counter.most_common` returns a list of (word, frequency) pairs, sorted by frequency
- `counter.most_common()[0][1]` if the second element of the first pair, so max frequency
- We are looping over `counter.most_common()` sorted by descending frequency first, then word
- `number_of_asterisks` is calculated by your formula. We use integer division `//` to get an integer result.
- We repeat an asterisk `number_of_asterisks` times and store the result in `asterisks`
- We print `asterisks` and `word`. Asterisks are right-aligned in a 50-characters-wide column.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in that for loop? (i'm brand new in python)

Comment: I'm also getting an error:
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Is it possible to switch the columns? Meaning have the word on the left and the asterisks on the right? 
If I may guess, to change that it would:
print('{:>50} {}'.format(key, asterisks))

Comment: 1) Added some explanations. 2) I fixed that. 3) Yes, but you have to be sure there are no words longer than 50 characters, and there's probably no need to `>` (right-align) the word.

Comment: Ideally you would find the longest word and set the width of the first column so it would fit, but no wider.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
import sys
import operator 
from collections import Counter
def candidateWord():
   with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f:
      text = f.read()
   words = [w.strip('!,.?1234567890-=@#$%^&*()_+')for w in text.lower().split()]
            #word_count[words] = word_count.get(words,0) + 1
   counter = Counter(words)

   # I added the code below...
   columns = 80
   n_occurrences = 10
   to_plot = counter.most_common(n_occurrences)
   labels, values = zip(*to_plot)
   label_width = max(map(len, labels))
   data_width = columns - label_width - 1
   plot_format = '{:%d}|{:%d}' % (label_width, data_width)
   max_value = float(max(values))
   for i in range(len(labels)):
     v = int(values[i]/max_value*data_width)
     print(plot_format.format(labels[i], '*'*v))

candidateWord()
```

outputs:

```
the |***************************************************************************
and |**********************************************                             
of  |******************************************                                 
to  |***************************                                                
a   |************************                                                   
in  |********************                                                       
that|******************                                                         
i   |****************                                                           
was |*************                                                              
it  |**********
```

Comment: The columns of the chart should be 2, the word and the asterisks.

Comment: I provided a code-example with the 2 columns.. still this defining a "scale" is key.. (e.g. in case of statistical outliers, for example)

Comment: Fun fact: you can nest fields in format strings. Try this: `"{:>{width}}".format('test', width=15)`

Comment: Gotta _love_ what you just taught me! Thanks!