# Incorrect Value being returned when counting the number of duplicate items in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

My function checks to see how many duplicates the first element of the list has within that list.

```
def duplicate(lst):
count=0
length = len(lst)

    for i in range(1,length):
        if lst[0]== lst[i]:
           count+=1
           print [(lst[i]),count]
```

For example:

```
duplicate(["hello", "hello","hello", "yes", "no"])=>['hello',2]
```

The above works fine, however say I just want to store a value for 'count' and I adjust my code to the following, the value 1 is always returned for 'count' instead of the correct 'count' of 2, using the previous example:

```
def duplicate(lst):
count=0
length = len(lst)

for i in range(1,length):
    if lst[0]== lst[i]:            
        count+=1
        return count
```

I'm aware there is a simpler approach to doing this using set(), however I want to know where I'm going wrong in my For Loop when accumulating values for the variable 'count'.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735406/converting-word-frequency-to-a-graphical-histogram-in-python) about converting word frequency to a histogram.  It seems that the process of creating a word histogram is very similar to the process of counting duplicates in a list, but I am not certain how much would be appropriate for what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the value from within the loop.  You need to dedent the return statement.  Your loop only executes once.

Comment: I did dedent it such that the return is inline with the 'if', however it still only returns 1. @patrick

Comment: @mista619 you need to dedent it another level. It needs to be level with the `for`. You only moved it out of the `if` statement. You should move it out of the loop completely.